# VBA Access - Array via textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

At the moment all my arrays are implemented in the vba code. This works fine

```
Dim COST As String
Dim GAT As String
Dim OND As String

COST = "C:\Users\update\COST.xlsb"
GAT = "C:\Users\BACKUP\GAT.xlsb"
OND = "C:\Users\BACKUP\OND.xlsb"

MyArray = Array(COST, GAT, OND)
```

However I would like to select the above arrays from a textbox via a form

Below code works but I have to implement the file path

```
MyArray = Array(Forms![LAYOUT_F]![Update_F])
```

with file path

```
MyArray = Array("C:\Users\BACKUP\" & Forms![LAYOUT_F]![Update_F])
```

Using the above will require me to be file name specific and doesn't take into account arrays plus the file paths are different

Is there a way of selecting declared arrays from a textbox

Answer (score 0):

I would use a multi-line textbox, where the user e.g. enters

```
C:\Users\update\COST.xlsb
C:\Users\BACKUP\GAT.xlsb
```

and then use the `Split()` function on the line breaks:

```
MyArray = Split(Me!myTextbox, vbCrLf)
```

But I my have misunderstood your question - not sure what you mean by "selecting declared arrays from a textbox".

Comment: selecting declared arrays from a textbox" - sorry probably me not typing correctly. The arrays that I have declared in the code e.g Dim COST As String

Comment: @Elixir: that's a string, not an array. You can't "select" from a textbox. Do you want the users to enter data into a textbox? Then see my answer. Or do you want them to select from a predefined list? Then you need e.g. a listbox.

Comment: I see, is there any way of the users entering in the textbox similar to what i had on my first code - (COST, GAT, OND)

Comment: @Elixir: Yes... three textboxes, labeled COST, GAT, OND. I have the feeling that you aren't quite sure yet what you actually want from the users. Or if you are, you haven't told us.